# Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at

Tags: android, cordova

Deviceready is not working because of this error.

```
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:924
```

line is :

```
  var messages = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

Comment: What's nativeApiProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to try to change the device or reinstall the application in the device 
that might be help.

Comment: How did this help, I have tried it in dozen devices and it gives me the same error everytime.